# using tnsnames.ora and sqlplus client without installing oracle 11g server on linux client

Tags: oracle, linux, connectivity, sqlplus, debian

I want to create a connection to remote Oracle server using SQLplus client and tnsnames.ora without installing Oracle 11g server on the Linux client. I used debian and bash script to generate reports from remote Oracle servers. Is this possible?

I tried installing SQLplus client but I can't find the tnsnames.ora files.

If possible, can you please give me an example of configuring SQLplus client to use tnsnames.ora files?

I have installed the "basic instant client" and the "sqlplus addition" package. I can connect normally with `sqlplus user/password@host:port/servicenames`. I want to create bash scripts to execute *.sql files on more than 10 instances. So, if I can just connect with `sqlplus user/pw@instance` It will look simple. it's is possible?

Update :
Solved by copying tnsnames.ora files to /etc.

refer to [this page](https://community.oracle.com/message/3588760#3588760) on post #3

Thanks to :
[Wernfried Domscheit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32815/wernfried-domscheit), [EdStevens](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/83595/edstevens), [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white)

Comment: There are examples of `tnsnames.ora` in the Oracle documentation; Google search also returns plenty of them.

Comment: @mustaccio, hi thanks for fast respone, I know the script config of tnsnames.ora, but I don't know how to config sqlplus to use tnsnames.ora.  usually tnsnames.ora comes with oracle 11g server.

Comment: You just set `$TNS_ADMIN` and plonk the file in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to tell Oracle to use the `tnsnames.ora` file at all.
For this open/create file `sqlnet.ora` and insert row like this:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)
```

You may add other methods for resolution, e.g. 'LDAP', see [DIRECTORY_PATH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm#sthref404). Entry `tnsnames` tells Oracle to use an `tnsnames.ora` file. As you see in documentation `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(tnsnames, onames, hostname)` is the default, so actually the `sqlnet.ora` file could be skipped in this case.

Regarding the location of these two files the answer is not trivial. Different application may search different folders and may have different rules of precedence.

Following folders could be part of search path:

- Folder defined by Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`
- Folder `${ORACLE_HOME}\network\admin`

  In case your files are located in different folder, it would be a good idea to put a symbolic link at this location pointing to your folder.
- Current folder
- Folder where your application binaries are stored

...and in case of Windows (just for information) also these ones

- Folder defined by Registry entry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN` resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`
- `machine.config`, resp. `web.config` file, section `oracle.manageddataaccess.client/version/settings/setting/@name="tns_admin"`

Comment: Thank you for hint. I place **sqlplus packages and the tnsnames.ora file** on `/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/` and set env `TNS_ADMIN` to that but I'm not set the `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)` because can't find **sqlnet.ora** file. I Think this will not work if you just set the TNS_ADMIN only. I try to copy tnsnames.ora to `/etc/` and it's works! Thanks Wernfriend :)

Answer (score 3):

tnsnames.ora doesn't "come with" anything.  The key is not that file, as it is nothing but a names resolution file. And sqlplus is nothing but a CLI application. If you want to connect to an Oracle database (or ANY database) you must have, at a minimum, the client software for that particular database product. For oracle you need to download and install the Oracle client. The easiest would be the "instant client", which you can download from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html.  If you want the full "Admin" or "Runtime" client, download from edelivery.com and select just the client software. Pay attention to the license terms.

Comment: If you could add your answer with configure sqlplus to use tnsnames.ora files, maybe it will help other. like add env on `$ export TNS_ADMIN=[path to tnsnames.ora]`. Thanks all member :)

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps...  (wrapped for readability)

```
sqlplus username/password@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)
    (HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)
    (INSTANCE_NAME=instance_name)))'
```